# Как в Python распечатать ход работы скрипта?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Существует ли метод, который позволяет распечатать выполнение скрипта( все что в нем происходит за все время работы его работы) ?

Для аналогии, хочу получить что-то подобное ( тут печатается ход распаковки пакета, я бы хотел - ход 'распаковки' скрипта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что вы вкладываете во "все что в нем происходит"?

Comment: например я создаю объект класса `MainClass` : `item = MainClass()` . И эта строчка кода выполняет сложный алгоритм (задействованы еще 3 класса). Хотел бы выписать выполнение этого алгоритма, грубо говоря то, как мы перескакиваем от метода к методу в ходе выполнения алгоритма.

Comment: print() в помощь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы когда нибудь обращали внимание, что выводит интерпретатор Python в случае даже простых ошибок? То самое "Traceback (most recent call last)"? Иногда этот список из пару десятков вызовов. И это именно "все, что происходит" при выполнении некоторой команды. Реально - каждой команды, просто выводится эта информация только при ошибке.

Теперь внимание -  вопрос. Вы представляете себе, что вы будете получать, если выводить реально "все что происходит" в более-менее сложном скрипте на пару десятков написанных вами строчек?

Если что-то надо остлеживать - лобовой прием -  используем print (там и то, что  действительно надо для анализа). Более профессиональный прием - используем логирование.

И на самый крайний случай - средства трассировки:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/traceback.html

Answer (score 1):

Вот такую функцию отладки успешного завершение какой-либо функции придумал,передается литеральное имя функции из программы:

```
def _0_(str_):
    print("Success ->", end = " ")
    print("function",str_)
```

Таких можно наделать,было бы желание)Но удобно.

Comment: `print("Success -> function", str_)`?

Comment: ну типа в calc_sin в конце пишем _0_("calc_sin")

Comment: Не, я просто не понял, в чем хитрость использования двух `print` :D

Comment: М D - наглядность (для меня) )